# Qt Signal/Slot connection from dialog window

Tags: qt

I am working on a GUI using Qt in Microsoft Visual Studio 12.

I have a pop up dialog that has a textEdit where I want to get some information from the user.
Then, when the user clicks the OK button, I want the information that the user entered to be displayed in a label on my main window. The code compiles but the label doesn't change.

Here is the code I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In my dialog .cpp file:

```
void PGTsettings::on_okButton_clicked() {
    QString str;
    str = ui.newFPS->toPlainText(); //newFPS is my textEdit
    emit buttonClick(str);
}
```

In my dialog .h file:

```
signals:
    void buttonClick(const QString& txt);
```

In my main window .cpp file:

```
GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    pgtsettings = new PGTsettings();
    QObject::connect(pgtsettings, SIGNAL(buttonClick(QString)), this, SLOT(onPGTsettingsok(QString)));
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

void GUI::onPGTsettingsok(QString txt)
{
    ui.label_7->setText(txt); //label_7 is the label I want to display the information in
}
```

In my main window .h file:

```
private slots:
    void onPGTsettingsok(QString txt);

private:
    PGTsettings* pgtsettings;
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem? The label doesn't change...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. Please check the connection of the Button with on_okButton_clicked().
Do you have

```
Q_OBJECT
```

in the window.h? 
Why do you use "QObject::connection ... " in window.cpp. You do not need it because your class is derived from QMainWindow.

The connection works well:

Signal:

```
void buttonClick(const QString& txt);
```

Slot:

```
void onPGTsettingsok(QString txt);
```

There should be no Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change signal signature in dialog .h file to

```
buttonClick(QString txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `PGTsettings::on_okButton_clicked()` gets executed at all? Put a `qDebug()`/`QMessageBox` in there and check. I think your slot in the dialog is not being called.

Is your PGTsettings derived from `QDialog` and does it run modal? If it is, just create a member variable in PGTsettings accessible from GUI and query this variable after modal-dialog returns (unblocks). You won't need a signal.

The code itself looks fine for me.